# Redirecting Site/List/Library/File URLs From 2010 to 2016 During Migration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, redirect

I'm migrating sites one-at-a-time from 2010 to 2016. My customers want a URL redirect in place down to individual file URLs.

So: https://sp.contoso.com/site/library/folder/file.xlsx will seamlessly redirect/rewrite to https://NEWSP.contoso.com/site/library/folder/file.xlsx.

I have URL Rewrite installed and attempted the below based on this article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1142def6-fce5-4bb0-ab50-0cb99c029405/migration-and-urlrewrite?forum=sharepointadmin

This works well for the first entry. All subsequent entries redirect users directly to the new site's home page, not to the list/library/file depth.

I know how to Google and have found dozens of articles, none of which cover my needs or work while other sites remain active in 2010 (I'm not done migrating, so some sites remain in 2010).

Has anyone been successful in doing this through URL Rewrite? If so, could you please provide screenshots or web.config code as to your parameters. 
Thanks!